# How do I delete a Facebook Test Account for which I don't have the App Access Token?

Tags: facebook, configuration, facebook-test-users

I have a Facebook test account linked to what is now my primary email, and I want to delete it. The problem is, even though I do have the password of the account, I don't have access to the app that this account is associated with (the reason for that being that this account was created around 5 or 6 years ago for testing Facebook apps at the time). Since I can't log in to Facebook with a test account (it throws an error stating that this is a test account), and I don't have an app token to use the API, I'm not sure how I can get rid of it. I wanted to try asking here first before hitting Facebook Help Center.